# Display the result after it submit through Ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

When submitted the results from my form and insert the values in sql after that i want message to display without refresh the page. Or probably refresh automated without user hit refresh.

Comment: check the documentation of ajax from jquery. Very easy to use

Comment: can you put the ajax call you have done in the code so that we can understand what exactly you have in order to answer you question correctly

Comment: Using ajax to send data and then reload the page on success feels very very wrong... Your are using **asynchronous** calls in a **synchronous** way.

Comment: @mor I know it is wrong but i can't think other way. I wanted to show the submitted message after insert in mysql database.

Answer (score 2):

on succes part you can display result.

```
        $.ajax({
                url: "file.php",
                data: "a=" + id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#anyid").html(data);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Already display the results through a php/sql script. The problem is that i have to refresh the page to see them.

Comment: if you are using ajax then you dont need to referesh page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'form.php',
// your data - this gets id="title" and put it on $_POST['val1']
 data: {val1:$('#title').val()},
// .done sends returned data to div id="bs"; you can use .append instead of .html for          overwriting the data.
}).done(function(data){
    $('#bs').html(data);
})
});
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use different function of jquery to show message if your require is success

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  data: "user_id=" + user_id,
  type: "POST",
success: function(data) {
  $('#message_div_id').text("Your message").show();
 }
   });
```

Comment: Already display the results through a php/sql script. The problem is that i have to refresh the page to see them.

Comment: Solved. Use $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});

Comment: if your div or message could not display your message then you should have to try with .show() ,slidedown() or toggle method to show up